# How to I select events in intervals e.g every 30 minutes?

Tags: esper

Im trying to select 1 event every 30 minutes.

I tried this and it works:

```
select e.timestamp from pattern[every e=Event -> timer:at(*/30,*,*,*,*)];
```

What other options are there to select in intervals?

I found this in the documentation:

```
select (select * from Event#lastevent) as e 
from pattern [every timer:interval(30 min)]
```

But returns null.

Im using external time if that matters.

Comment: What does "1 event" mean please, the first event? The last event? Some specific event? The first statement you have there returns every event but each event delayed by 30 minutes. When I run the second statement in the EPL online tool it does not return null. Another option is "select * from Event.win:firstevent().win:time(30)".

Comment: I only want to update the listener every X minutes/hours with the most recent event at that time. The last EPL u suggested does the same thing as the first EPL i posted. I think that works.

Comment: this explains my confusion. Since I use external timer with timestamps Esper round to the neasrest 30 min and only release that event, then it jumps to the next rounded 30 minutes since there are no events between. Does that make sense?

Comment: Look at the difference between "CurrentTimeSpanEvent" versus "CurrentTimeEvent".